# radian R console

Tags: python, r, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use radian as modermized frontend for R console. I run linux debian debian buster on my workstation and vscode as editor. I get several error while I eval a function. I get an error for each line such as they are not from the same function but such as each line is independent:

This is a function:

```
sumstats <- function(z) {
  MEAN <- apply(z, 2, mean)
  MEDIAN <- apply(z, 2, median)
  SD <- apply(z, 2, sd)
  SE <- apply(z, 2, function(x) {sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))})
  CV <- apply(z, 2, function(x) {sd(x) / mean(x)})
  result <- data.frame(MEAN, MEDIAN, SD, SE, CV)
  return(result)
}
```

and this is the radian out:

```
r$> sumstats <- function(z) { 
          MEAN <- apply(z, 2, mean) 
    }                                                                                                                                                                              
  result <- data.frame(MEAN, MEDIAN, SD, SE, CV)

  return(result)
}
r$>   MEDIAN <- apply(z, 2, median)                                                                                                                                                
Error in apply(z, 2, median) : object 'z' not found

r$>   SD <- apply(z, 2, sd)                                                                                                                                                        
Error in apply(z, 2, sd) : object 'z' not found

r$>   SE <- apply(z, 2, function(x) {sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))})                                                                                                                     
Error in apply(z, 2, function(x) { : object 'z' not found

r$>   CV <- apply(z, 2, function(x) {sd(x) / mean(x)})                                                                                                                             
Error in apply(z, 2, function(x) { : object 'z' not found

r$>   result <- data.frame(MEAN, MEDIAN, SD, SE, CV)                                                                                                                               
Error in data.frame(MEAN, MEDIAN, SD, SE, CV) : object 'MEAN' not found

r$>   return(result)                                                                                                                                                               
Error: object 'result' not found

r$> }                                                                                                                                                                              
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

r$>
```

Using the *classic* R console all works great.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you define z anywhere

Comment: Or maybe I'm confused because it looks like maybe you didn't do a great job with your copy paste.

Comment: z is the function variable and is declared at the beginning of the function... it seems that radian ignore the curly braces and eval each line stendalone

Comment: Copy/paste issue...sorry

Comment: What you have pasted in the second chunk doesn't match the first chunk and it does end the function with a second curly brace so I honestly think it's doing what it should be. You want to either try copy pasting again or updating the question

Comment: I know, but now is correct. What I have posted on the second chunk is the output from the radian console

Comment: So you intend for the line after MEAN to be a curly bracket?

Answer (score 1):

Solved [here](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/809). It was not a radian issue but a vscode issue